# Background-size:cover makes background image full-size instead of fitting to div

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

. Hello, I'm trying to figure out why when I use `background-size: cover` on an image that is placed as a div's background by javascript that the image does not shrink to the div's size but instead remains full-sized where only the part that is in the div is visible.

I have thought about using the javascript to set the images attributes when it is set as the background image but that seems to be a hacky solution and not addressing the problem I am obviously making somewhere.

Any help or insight as to where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

CSS:

```
#module-background
    {
        text-align: center;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #fff;
        background: #888;
        background-size: cover;

        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    #module-background a 
    {
        color: #fff;
    }

    #module-background h1 
    {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: 0 0.3em;
        line-height: 1em;
    }

    #module-background p 
    {
        padding: 0 1em;
    }

    #module-background section 
    {
      min-height: 100%;
      text-shadow:  -1px -1px 0 #000,
                    1px -1px 0 #000,
                    -1px 1px 0 #000,
                    1px 1px 0 #000;  
    }
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <section  id="module-background">
        <h1 id="city">Dummy Text</h1>
        <p>
            <span id="temperature">
            </span>
            <span id="weather">
                Current temperature and weather conditions
            </span>
        </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: `background-size:100% 100%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line from your CSS Style:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: "Theeeeerrrrre gooooesss mmyy hheeeerrrrooooo. Watch him as he goes." Lol. Thanks, completely forgot about that from earlier. Will accept answer after 10 minute wait is up.